# How to insert/update data after login in Meteor

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, authentication, collections

I am trying to add data to a `Collection` after the user has either logged in or signed up.

The flow of the application is as follow :

1. The unregistered user is allowed to enter some values in a form group;
2. Once submitted, the form checks if the user is registered or not, and if not, the user is prompted to log in / sign up;
3. The user is logged in, and the `Collection` should have a new entry with the data previously entered.

Here is the way I do this:

*/imports/ui/components/form.js*

```
Template.form.events({
    "click #submit" : function(e,t) {
        let address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        Session.set('address' : address);
        }
    }
})
```

*/imports/api/collection/methods.js*

```
Meteor.methods({
    'collection.insert'(address) {
    // Perform checks
    // Insert into Collection
    }
})
```

*/lib/config/accounts.js*

```
var onSubmit = function (error, state) {
    Meteor.apply('collection.insert', [address]);
};

AccountsTemplates.configure({
    onSubmitHook: onSubmit
});
```

My problem is that I can't use `Session` variables with methods called from the server.

I am also having a hard time doing so with the `onSubmitHook` from the `useraccounts` package.

How would you go about inserting / updating pre-existing data after the user has logged in?

Comment: Do you use a router? Can you show a bit of code of your form?

Comment: I am not changing routes between operation 1 and 2. Otherwise I'm using FlowRouter.

Comment: No need for a session here. This can all be solved in one template using template methods and some reactive variables. Do you intend to save the data in step 1 already or will you finally save in step 3?

Comment: Ideally I would store the data available in step 1, and update the entry with the userId at step 3.